# Problems publishing messages with kafka running on mesos DCOS

Tags: apache-kafka, mesos, mesosphere, apache-zookeeper, dcos

I have a small cluster running DCOS. I'm able to successfully install kafka following [this](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.7/usage/service-guides/kafka/quick-start/) guide. running

```
$ dcos kafka connection
```

gives

```
{
  "address": [
    "10.131.17.126:9475",
    "10.131.24.6:9655",
    "10.131.14.192:9181"
  ],
  "zookeeper": "master.mesos:2181/dcos-service-kafka",
  "dns": [
    "broker-0.kafka.mesos:9475",
    "broker-1.kafka.mesos:9655",
    "broker-2.kafka.mesos:9181"
  ]
}
```

I can create topics and I've examined zookeeper with the cli tool and the state appears to be good

```
get /dcos-service-kafka/brokers/ids/0
{"jmx_port":-1,"timestamp":"1474206074029","endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://10.131.17.126:9475"],"host":"10.131.17.126","version":3,"port":9475}
get /dcos-service-kafka/brokers/ids/1
{"jmx_port":-1,"timestamp":"1474206120002","endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://10.131.24.6:9655"],"host":"10.131.24.6","version":3,"port":9655}
get /dcos-service-kafka/brokers/ids/2
{"jmx_port":-1,"timestamp":"1474206122985","endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://10.131.14.192:9181"],"host":"10.131.14.192","version":3,"port":9181}
```

However when I try publishing

```
echo "Hello, World." | ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.131.17.126:9475, 10.131.24.6:9655, 10.131.14.192:9181 --topic topic1
```

I get

```
[2016-09-18 18:49:32,909] ERROR Error when sending message to topic topic1 with key: null, value: 13 bytes with error: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

I suspect it might be something to do with private vs. public ip addresses and perhaps host.name in server.properties.

Can anyone give some suggestions as to how I might debug (and hopefully fix!) the problem so I can successfully publish messages?

Thanks

AJ

Answer (score 1):

Edit: For anyone looking in the future.  [This was a problem in /etc/hosts caused by a terraform script](https://github.com/mesosphere/dcos-kafka-service/issues/259#issuecomment-250155184).

Your suspicion is correct.  Those are private IP addresses which are not addressable from outside the cluster.  In order to communicate with Kafka you will either have to setup a VPN such that those IP addresses become reachable, or run your publishing command on a machine in the cluster.

Also, it looks like you're running on a DC/OS version earlier than 1.8.  If you use 1.8, you'll get an easier broker endpoint to use, regardless of the dynamically assigned IP addresses.  You can used the named VIP `broker.kafka.l4lb.thisdcos.directory:9092` however this is only addressable from machines in the cluster.

Setting up haproxy or nginx to point to the named VIP is also a way to get easy external access to a service (in this case Kafka) running on a DC/OS cluster.  You would want to ensure that these proxies run on a public Agent.  [See here for more details](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/tutorials/public-app/).

Here is an example of installing, producing and consuming from the default Kafka installation:

```
~ $ dcos package install kafka
Installing Marathon app for package [kafka] version [1.1.11-0.10.0.0]
Installing CLI subcommand for package [kafka] version [1.1.11-0.10.0.0]
New command available: dcos kafka
DC/OS Kafka Service is being installed.

        Documentation: https://docs.mesosphere.com/usage/services/kafka/
        Issues: https://docs.mesosphere.com/support/
~ $ dcos kafka connection
{
  "address": [
    "10.0.3.64:9951",
    "10.0.3.68:9795",
    "10.0.3.66:9531"
  ],
  "zookeeper": "master.mesos:2181/dcos-service-kafka",
  "dns": [
    "broker-0.kafka.mesos:9951",
    "broker-1.kafka.mesos:9795",
    "broker-2.kafka.mesos:9531"
  ],
  "vip": "broker.kafka.l4lb.thisdcos.directory:9092"
}
~ $ dcos kafka topic create topic0
{
  "message": "Output: Created topic \"topic0\".\n"
}
~ $ dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader
core@ip-10-0-7-56 ~ $ wget http://download.nextag.com/apache/kafka/0.10.0.1/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.tgz
core@ip-10-0-7-56 ~ $ tar xf kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1.tgz
core@ip-10-0-7-56 ~ $ cd kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1
core@ip-10-0-7-56 ~/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1 $ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list broker.kafka.l4lb.thisdcos.directory:9092 --topic topic0
This is a message
This is another message
^Ccore@ip-10-0-7-56 ~/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1 $ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper master.mesos:2181/dcos-service-kafka --topic topic0 --from-beginning
This is a message
This is another message
^CProcessed a total of 2 messages
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list 10.0.3.64:9951,10.0.3.68:9795,10.0.3.66:9531 --topic topic0
foo
bar
baz
^Ccore@ip-10-0-7-56 ~/kafka_2.11-0.10.0.1 $ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper master.mesos:2181/dcos-service-kafka --topic topic0 --from-beginning
This is a message
This is another message
foo
bar
baz
^CProcessed a total of 5 messages
```

Comment: I've updated to 1.8 now, thanks. I am ssh'ing on to one of the broker nodes as per the user guide `dcos node ssh --master-proxy --leader`. I can ping all internal ports from there and from within the docker container

Comment: Should add it's still not working. Not sure using a VPN will fix this, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this still doesn't work for me. If I follow the same steps as you above I get:

Answer (score 1):

Update - this does appear to have been caused by missing entries in /etc/hosts. I've updated my terraform script to write these during setup and your example above now works as expected.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Great! Glad you reached a solution. Sorry I couldn't be more help.